Cache aware job placement algorithm
I am looking for advice on selecting or building a job placement algorithm.
In my company, we have a simple computing platform built on top of Kubernetes. Multiple clients, send compute jobs to a single Kafka topic, multiple workers continuously pull for new tasks from the queue, execute jobs and go back to pick up next tasks. Any worker can execute any job, the system has practically a single queue.
I need to modify this system to get data/cache aware. Imagine that each job requires some data [D1, D2, ... Dn], when this job lands on a worker [Wi] it first needs to retrieve this data and cache it locally before it can start execution. When a new job comes in with a requirement for some data [Dx], I want it to be assigned to a "worker pool" where workers already cached that data [Dx].
I am free to modify the architecture to implement the new functionality, for example we can replace Kafka or use multiple topics or introduce some look up tables etc.
Requirements:

The number of datasets is not known in advance, new datasets come at runtime.
Consider that worker can store/cache infinite number of datasets.
It has to be a push based mechanism where worker selects a queue/topic to get the next task from.

Perhaps an algorithm like this already exists. I would appreciate any direction.

I think @IvovanderVeeken has the best approach. Use a distributed cache, and then your system doesn't need to care which worker processes the job.

A distributed cache is simple, but their are cases like the issue described where the data to be cached is large >GB and needed with fast low latency access, such that a distributed cache would require excessive bandwidth requirements.

The normal Kafka architecture would be multiple partitions per topic (so that you can have multiple consumers), and to give each message partition key. Here, you might want the data ID as the key. Unfortunately, you need multiple items of data (so can't have a single partition key), and it seems you don't really want to utilize partition-based concurrency. A better solution may be a shared cache (k8s volume) between the workers – storage is probably virtualized anyway, there's no latency difference between my cache and another worker's cache. You might want a network file system like Ceph.

Thank you for all of your suggestions. I have considered a shared cache (and it might be the final solution if I will not find anything better), but it might not work well if you need to share large datasets (as mentioned above). Shared k8s volume will work well within the scope of a Node, but we have 100s of nodes, so this reduces the problem by the order of Pods per Node.

These is my naive thoughts:  (1) the set of datasets required per task [Dk, Dj, Dm] form a  unique Kafka topic. (2) If a client doesn't see a topic it creates it, (3) we have fast lookup of existing topics in some cache (or use Kafka API), (3) a worker based on the data it has, knows which topics it can consume and chooses one based on the largest number of tasks there (4)  worker consumes tasks until queue is empty (5) then it uses lookup to select another Topic based on the logic above. Feels a bit complicated, but I can't find a better option so far.

Is the cached data static? Or do those jobs actually modify it? If so, then how often? And is reading stale data a big problem?
